# running class method multiple times in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This might be a stupid question,

I am running a class method inside a rails 2 console as follows:

```
>> load 'test_pass.rb'
=> ["TestPass"]
>> TestPass.test_data(TestPass.run_data)
=> ["test1", "test2"]
```

But if i wan to run the above method 50 times in loop, i tried the following:

```
    >> 50.times.each do |i| TestPass.test_data(TestPass.run_data)) end
    => 50
```

I get 50. Shouldnt it run 50 times and return me back results each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) method.

```
50.times.collect { TestPass.test_data(TestPass.run_data)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.times` returns the number.

If you want to collect results, use collect.

```
50.times.collect do TestPass.test_data(TestPass.run_data)) end
```